# OnClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have one very strange problem.

I have the following link in react

```
<a onClick={this.props.onClick} name={this.props.name} style={{cursor: 'pointer', display: 'block', textAlign: 'center'}}>
       <span className="regHeaderText">{this.props.value}</span>
       <FontAwesome name={this.props.icon} className="faIcon"/>
</a>
```

And it's looks like :

[image]

But the problem is if I click on text *NEXT* or on font awesome icon I get **undefined** as name of the link .

Only if I click somewhere left of text *NEXT*, in this yellow box only then I get right name.

If I create links instead spans, like :

```
<a onClick={this.props.onClick} name={this.props.name} style={{cursor: 'pointer', display: 'block', textAlign: 'center'}}>
     <a onClick={this.props.onClick} name={this.props.name} className="regHeaderText">{this.props.value}</a>
     <a onClick={this.props.onClick} name={this.props.name}><FontAwesome name={this.props.icon} className="faIcon"/></a>
</a>
```

Then it works, but is there any solution to do it without creating links inside link?

**EDIT**

```
onClick: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var field = event.target.name;
    alert("The name is : " + field);
}
```

Comment: can u show us your onClick function?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question.

Comment: @Boky Create jsfiddle contain css querys. Your demo should be like this image that we test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using e.target in your onClick handler. When you click on the span the event bubbles up to the handler on the link but the target will be the span and not the a.

To circumvent this you can create a bound onClick with the name of the link

```
<a onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, this.props.name)}
```

The first argument to your onClick method will be the name and the second the event.

Comment: If you ment `<a onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, this.props.name)} name={this.props.name} style={{cursor: 'pointer', display: 'block', textAlign: 'center'}}>` , now  get in cosole log _Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See RegistrationPage_ and _TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function_

Comment: so based on you `onClick` function, this way you can change it to   
```onClick: function(name, event) { alert("The name is " + name) }```

Comment: That did the trick. Of course, so obvious. And I still could not find a problem. Thanks